# sql query to search column for string for specific pattern that i need

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have made a search bar for searching string my query is

```
$q = $_GET('val');
$sqlquery=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tickets_search WHERE (ticket_date LIKE 
'%".$q."%') OR (car_number LIKE '%".$q."%') order by ticket_id desc");
```

Now when I search for HU-GG 6 it gives me two results
see here:

Snippet-1 : [HU-GG 6-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSFZz.png)

When I search for HU-GG-6.it gives me another result
see here:

Snippet-2: [HU-GG-6-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUIY4.png)

What I want that is to show all three results with HU-GG-6 or HU-GG 6 whatever I write.It should show me all three results.

Comment: It's imperative that you spend some time learning about SQL injection. Code like this is a major security risk.

Comment: it is my admin side work not for users

Comment: In addition, why are you comparing the `ticket_date` and `car_number` columns to the same thing?

Comment: HU-GG-6 or HU-GG 6 wont give you all 3 results if there is some like that. untill you pass HU-GG then it will show all of them

Comment: @ TIM Biegeleisen I wants the result for only car_number also i am searching for ticket date if i wants to.SO it gives me whether the date search result or car number result whatever i wants , it depends on my search

Comment: @Exprator HU-GG contains more than 100 results

Comment: Can anyone please provide me the possible solution to get all three results.

Comment: Is your data format always same and you wanna same search for other data also ??

Comment: what I wants is to get all data for searched strings that matched in a column, I means when i write HU-GG 6 or HU-GG-6 then search query should search for HUGG6  in my required column, so removing all white space and dashes would give me the required result what i think. Otherwise you can guide me for correct logic.

Comment: It shouldn't matter where the code is located, what it does or who has access to it, you should be protecting against SQL injection everywhere. Someone who is supposedly trusted could easily break your code by accident.

Comment: @Enstage I appreciate your suggestion , and I know that it is critical for sql injection but at this time I have to make it by this method as i dont have time to go for other methods and read about prevention of sql injection and then implement the code accordingly.Just for urgency i am doing this.Thanks dear

Comment: If you have any solution to prevent this from sql injection then i highly appreciate your solution and implement directly to my code.Just because of short time i dont wants to go for searching prevention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TRY THIS:**  You can use `REPLACE` to satisfy both of your conditions but I am not sure how much it will help and please adjust `REPLACE` in `PHP` if it's not correct:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tickets_search 
WHERE (ticket_date LIKE '%".$q."%') OR 
     (REPLACE(car_number, ' ', '-') LIKE REPLACE('%".$q."%', ' ', '-')) 
ORDER BY ticket_id DESC
```